# Trouble formatting multiple date styles with lubridate

Tags: r, date, formatting, lubridate

I am formatting one column that contains the date of a record. In the column there are many formats of the date and I need to convert them into one consistent format.

I tried using lubridate()and the parse_date_time() function.
I also tried with the column as a character and as a factor

This is what the date column looks like (with over 100,000 rows)

```
Date.of.Record 
2018-01-01     
20180102     
2018/01/03  
2018-01-04  
2018-01-05
20180106
```

And id like to format them to this:

```
Date.of.Record 
20180101     
20180102     
20180103  
20180104  
20180105
20180106
```

And this  its the code I tried:

```
library(lubridate)
date <- parse_date_time(bind$Date.of.Record, orders =c(ymd()))
date2 <- as.Date(bind$Date.of.Record, "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")
```

The code for 'date" doesn't work at all and the code for 'date2' produces all NAs.

I realize that I could subset the data into different datasets by date format then combine after I format properly, but I expect there is a much more efficient way to do this. I am still new to R and try to learn the best way to work with large datasets

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: If the dates you start out with are all in the correct order (year, month, date), just with various punctuation in between, could you just treat them as strings and remove any non-digit characters? Such as `str_remove_all(Date.of.Record, "\\D+")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
bind$Date.of.Record <- format(anydate(bind$Date.of.Record), "%Y%m%d")
bind$Date.of.Record
#[1] "20180101" "20180102" "20180103" "20180104" "20180105" "20180106"
```

If it needs to be numeric, wrap with `as.numeric`

---

The `orders` would be a string format

```
library(lubridate)
format(parse_date_time(bind$Date.of.Record, orders = "ymd"), "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "20180101" "20180102" "20180103" "20180104" "20180105" "20180106"
```

#### data

```
bind <- structure(list(Date.of.Record = c("2018-01-01", "20180102", "2018/01/03", 
 "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "20180106")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```